# How to make my scoring system update the right variable?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Please take a look at my code at http://pastebin.com/nHB81pVW

As you may notice, there are a few classes which are colored bubbles. 
inside those classes there's a function called addScore which calls one of the increaseColor functions at the bottom of the code in the pastebin.

When the bubbles burst, it seems like a random score is updated instead of the corresponding color... how can I make it update the right color?

Please let me know if I need to explain myself better

Comment: Some tips:  1st - learn about inheritance (all your bubbles should inherit from a base class that has all the identical or similar code), then you can just override functions to customize each bubble class.

Comment: 2nd - `MovieClip(root)` isn't good practice.   Either use `parent`, dispatch an event, or pass in a reference to the root class in your bubble constructors. OR use a static variable (but that's not always good practice either).  These methods are easier to debug and cleaner

Comment: In regards to the existing answer below. When you splice an array with an iterator: `array.splice(i,1)`,  you've now removed the element that was at the position of `i`,  so `array[i]` will either be out of bounds, or a different element than it was before the splice.  That's why you need to splice **AFTER** any other references to  array[i].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is your error:

```
bubbleList.splice(i,1);
bubbleList[i].addScore();
```

That's wrong. Let's say you have an array: `[1, 2, 3]`, and `i` is 1. When you do a `splice(i, 1);`, you actually perform `splice(1, 1);` and the result would be `[1, 3]`, right?
But then you do `bubbleList[i]`, which is actually `array(1)`, and in our case of `[1, 3]`, the item with index `1` would be **3**.

Shortly said, you are removing an element and then you do `addScore` on the **next** element from the array.

Instead, do this:

```
bubbleList.splice(1, 1)[0].addScore();
```

`splice` would return you an array of elements that were removed (in your case single one), and so you get the element as position 0 and perform `addScore` on it.

Cheers!

Edit: or if you want it to be more clear - first `addScore`, then `splice` ;)

Comment: thanks Andrey, I tried this and my game now crashes when this line is executed... any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just use the second option - first `addScore`, then `splice` :) I cannot say what's wrong without even an error message ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by first addscore and then splice, but here's what I did:
      bubbleList[i].addScore();      bubbleList.splice(i,1);

this is the addScore function inside the class:   public function addScore()
  {
    MovieClip(root).increaseBlue();
  }
And the error messages I get are these: 
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at Game::BlueBubble/addScore()
at GameController/removeBubble()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

Comment: PS. I'm sorry I don't know how to format the code in the comment xD

Comment: Well this is some other error, on Tick you cannot access the root.. I don't know, these classes are not present :)

Comment: I pasted the class code here http://pastebin.com/FwjEVZ0A
all other classes are essentially the same with just a different color. Could you take a loot at it please? :)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers and tips.

I placed addScore before removeChild and splice and that fixed the problem.

Thanks :)